# Rails database testing and clearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, model

Let's imagine this:

```
class ModTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   test "something" do
     m1 = Mod.new
     # test some things
     assert m1.save
   end

   test "whatever" do
     m2 = Mod.new
     # test other things
     assert m2.save
   end
end
```

Before the 2nd test case gets executed, the one called `whatever`, will the database be cleared, or will it contain the object added by the first test case? 
Can this behaviour be controlled/customised?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure on what the default behavior is, I've been using the [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem for this purpose.  Below is the relevant code in my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'database_cleaner'

RSpec.configure do |config|

  # Truncated for brevity

  config.before :suite do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end

  config.before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

One caveat, if you go this route make sure you take out the `config.use_transactional_fixtures` line in the default `spec_helper.rb` if you use the transaction cleaning strategy - leaving it set to true causes transaction within transaction errors (at least for sqlite databases).